# How can we log the time it took to load a set of records from kafka topic onto database

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I'm using JDBC sink connector to load data from kafka topic to postgres.
In my topic, I have around 100k records.
Now need to know if I can identify when connector started loading records and ended loading all those 100k records to database.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

All messages are timestamped, so this allows you to preserve the timestamps of messages.
Add to your configuration

```
...
"transforms": "timestamp",
"transforms.timestamp.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.TimestampConverter$Value",
"transforms.timestamp.target.type": "Timestamp",
"transforms.timestamp.field":"timestamp",
"transforms.timestamp.format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
...
```

You may also need to configure the [schema registry](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/connect.html#) with the corresponding `value.converter`.

But it will give you information about the time the message appeared in the kafka. If you want to know the time of writing to the database, then just create an additional field with the default value = now (). Then you will have up-to-date information of data recording in the database.

Comment: Hi, @asanisimov I'm not suppose to modify/alter the tables. Is any other way to get the timings?

Comment: Then I do not understand what you mean by "find out the time". Since you are using `confluent-platform`, you can go to the topic from where you read the data and see in the` Consumption` tab the start time of reading, or check the connector logs.

Comment: sorry, I'm not using confluent platform, I'm using kafka which is downloaded apache site and runnning on windows (.bat files)